# Diferencia entre undefined y null en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Cuál es la diferencia en JavaScript entre una variable `undefined` y una variable `null`, cómo puedo saber si una variable está `null`, `undefined` o ambos, también quisiera saber si son lo mismo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined` es una variable global y a la vez un tipo de dato. La variable `undefined` es de tipo `undefined`.

Una variable declarada **sin valor** asume *implícitamente* el valor  `undefined` y su tipo es `undefined`

```js
var variable1;
console.log('variable 1 es', variable1);
console.log('el tipo de variable1 es', typeof variable1);
```

Bajo ciertas condiciones `undefined` se puede sobreescribir y eso tiene consecuencias (en modo estricto y navegadores modernos, no debiera poderse). Sin embargo, aunque actualmente su reescritura no es posible, **intentarlo no arroja un error**:

```js
undefined = 5; // no se redefine en realidad, pero no tira error
console.log('undefined es', undefined);
```

`null` en cambio *no es una variable*. Es un tipo de dato. Un **primitivo**. Una variable debe ser declarada *explícitamente* como `null` para señalar que **sí tiene valor**, pero éste es un valor vacío. Y el tipo de esa variable no es `null` sino `object`. (esto último es una anomalía que existe desde siempre).

```js
var variable2=null;
console.log('variable 2 es', variable2);
console.log('variable 2 es de tipo ',typeof variable2);
```

`null` no sólo no puede ser redeclarado, sino que intentarlo tira un error:

```js
null=5;
```

Otra anomalía: dos variables con valor `null` son de tipo `object` y, sin ser la misma variable, sí son estrictamente iguales (esto no se cumple para los objetos de js en general)

```js
var variable1=null,
variable2=null;
console.log('variable1 es === a variable2?', variable1 === variable2);
```

Si comparas `undefined` con `null`, como los tipos de datos son distintos, `undefined` no es estrictamente igual a `null`. Pero si haces una comparación no estricta, sí son iguales.

```js
console.log('Undefined es === a null?', undefined === null);
console.log('Undefined es == a null?', undefined == null);
```

Finalmente, si tienes una variable con un valor, nada te impide asignarle valor `undefined`

```js
var a=5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a);
```

Pero es una convención que uses `undefined` para verificar si una variable o propiedad existe, y en cambio uses `null` si quieres vaciarla.

Answer (score 7):

Segun encontre en la documentación oficial de ECMA es undefined

> undefined es una propiedad del objeto global, es decir, una variable de alcance global. El valor inicial de undefined es el valor primitivo undefined.En navegadores modernos (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined es una propiedad no-configurable, no-grabable según la especificación ECMAScript 5. Aún cuando este no sea el caso, evite sobreescribirlo.Una variable a la que no se le ha asignado valor es de tipo undefined. Un método o sentencia también devuelve undefined si la variable que se está evaluando no tiene asignado un valor. Una función devuelve undefined si no se ha devuelto un valor

esto lo encontre en [ECMA](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/undefined)

Y sobre null

> El valor null es un literal (no una propiedad del objeto global como podría ser undefined). En APIs, se devuelve null normalmente dónde se espera un objeto pero éste no es relevante. Al comparar con null o  undefined hay que tener en cuenta las diferencias entre los operadores de igualdad (==) e identidad (===) (con el primero se realiza una conversión de tipo).

Answer (score 1):

Explicación con ejemplos:

El valor por defecto de una variable o atributo es `undefined`. En navegadores antiguos este valor estaba establacido como un atributo de la clase Window, y podía ser redefinido. Eso podía dar muchos problemas y por ello en mucha literatura antigua recomendaban nunca hacer una comparación directa. Hoy día los navegadores no permiten redefinirlo y una comparación directa funciona siempre:

```js
var hola;

console.log(hola)

//comparación directa
if (hola===undefined) {
  console.log('Hola no tiene valor definido');
}

if (typeof hola === 'undefined') {
  console.log('Hola sigue sin valor definido');
}

if (undefined==null) {
  console.log('Cuidado al compararlo con null, == no los distingue')
}

if (!(undefined === null)) {
  console.log('En cambio === los distingue');
}
```

El valor `null` es útil cuando quieres expresamente distinguir entre "valor no definido" y "sin valor":

```js
var resultado;



function test() {
  if (resultado === undefined) {
     console.log('No se ha definido aún');
  } else if (resultado===null) {
     console.log('se ha definido como null');
  }
}

setTimeout(()=> resultado=null)

test();


setTimeout(()=> test());
```

También sirve para detectar atributos no definidos. Y, por supuesto, es un valor "falso", lo cual es útil cuando quieres llamar a una función que quizá no está presente:

```js
var objeto= {
  a: 1,
  c: function () {
      console.log('hola');
     }
}

console.log('el atributo a es:' + objeto.a);
console.log('el atributo b es:' + objeto.b);

if (objeto.d) { // no existe, la condición no se cumple
   objeto.d();
}

if (objeto.c && typeof objeto.c === 'function') {
   objeto.c();
}
```