# Validar prompt en js para evitar aceptar valores nulos

Tags: javascript

Estoy validando el valor que obtengo de un prompt en js pero el usuario al momento de darle aceptar se obtiene un valor nulo, es decir si el usuario no escribio nada y le da aceptar el prompt se cierra y obtengo valores nulos. En cambio si le da cancelar el prompt persiste y vuelve a pedir los datos al usuario.

```
       var nick;       
        while(true){
            var valor = prompt('Cual es su nombre?')
            
            if (valor == null){
                alert("Por favor ingrese un nick valido")
            }else{
                nick = valor;
                break;
            }

        }
```

Alguna sugerencia les agradesco.
gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia la condición del `if` de:

```
valor == null
```

**A**

```
valor === ''
```

Ya que devuelve una `string` vacía.

**EDITO**:

Si también quieres verificar que aunque le de a cancelar le siga preguntando, puedes evaluar con `null` también. Por lo que podrías evaluar con un OR `||`.

**Código final**:

```
var nick;       
while(true){

    var valor = prompt('Cual es su nombre?')  
    if (valor === '' || valor === null){
        alert("Por favor ingrese un nick valido")
    }
    else {
        nick = valor;
        break;
    }

}
```

Más info:

- [Null Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/null)
- [Diferencia entre undefined y null en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119964/diferencia-entre-undefined-y-null-en-javascript/119968)

Comment: perdón si logro validar como indicas pero ahora si el usuario le da cancelar no obtengo nada.. en ese caso deveria de volver a llamar a la función?

Comment: En ese caso también podrías verificar `null`, modifico respuesta.

Comment: Excelente Adrián. Gracias por tu colaboración. Es para un chat en donde debo de pedir obligatoriamente el nick del participante. Excelente.

Answer (score 0):

Este código en JavaScript realiza dos acciones principales: pide al usuario que ingrese su nombre mediante un cuadro de diálogo **(prompt()** y luego muestra un mensaje de bienvenida personalizado usando un cuadro de alerta **(alert()**

```js
// Pedir al usuario que ingrese su nombre usando prompt()
var userInput = "";
while (userInput === "" || userInput === null) {
    userInput = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre:");
}

// Mostrar el valor ingresado por el usuario usando alert()
alert("Hola, " + userInput + " ! Bienvenido/a á Academia ONE");
```

. Aquí está el desglose paso a paso del código:

**var userInput = "";**  : Crea una variable llamada userInput y la inicializa como una cadena vacía.

**while (userInput === "" || userInput === null) { userInput = prompt("Por favor, ingrese su nombre:"); }** : Esto crea un bucle while que se ejecutará mientras userInput esté vacía **("")** o sea null. En cada iteración del bucle, se muestra un cuadro de diálogo pidiendo al usuario que ingrese su nombre usando **prompt()**. La entrada del usuario se asigna a la variable userInput. El bucle continuará ejecutándose hasta que el usuario ingrese algo y haga clic en "Aceptar" o presione "Cancelar". Si el usuario hace clic en "Cancelar", **prompt()** devuelve null, y el bucle también se detendrá en ese caso.

**alert("Hola, " + userInput + " ! Bienvenido/a á Academia ONE ¡");**: Después de que el usuario ingrese su nombre, se utiliza **alert()** para mostrar un mensaje de bienvenida personalizado. En este mensaje, el nombre ingresado por el usuario se concatena con otras cadenas para formar el mensaje completo que se muestra en el cuadro de alerta.

En resumen, el código solicita al usuario que ingrese su nombre a través de un cuadro de diálogo, y luego muestra un mensaje de bienvenida personalizado usando un cuadro de alerta. El bucle while garantiza que el usuario no pueda dejar el campo en blanco o hacer clic en "Cancelar" sin ingresar un nombre válido.

Comment: Solo por si no sabías: [La IA generativa (ej.: ChatGPT) está prohibida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462) y [¿Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable?](/help/gpt-policy)