# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre 'null' y 'undefined' en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, programación-bajo-nivel

Cuál es la diferencia en JavaScript entre una variable undefined y una variable null, cómo puedo saber si una variable está null, undefined o ambos, también quisiera saber si son lo mismo.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Diego. Aquí primero se anima a los usuarios a hacer un poco de investigación y experimentación antes de realizar la pregunta aquí. Entonces, mi pregunta hacia ti es: Qué has investigado al respecto?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Diferencia entre undefined y null en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119964/diferencia-entre-undefined-y-null-en-javascript)

Comment: JS es un lenguaje de alto nivel. Pon el mouse encima de la etiqueta [programación-bajo-nivel] para saber a qué se refiere :)

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se hizo y tiene respuestas. Si quieren dar su propia respuesta, mejor háganlo en la otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En JavaScript, `null` y `undefined` son dos valores especiales que indican la ausencia de un valor o la falta de definición de una variable. Aunque a menudo se utilizan de manera similar, tienen diferencias sutiles en su significado y uso:

1. `null`:

   - `null` es un valor que se usa para indicar explícitamente que una variable no tiene ningún valor o que el valor no existe.
   - Es un valor asignado por el programador para indicar la falta de un valor específico.
   - `null` es un valor primitivo.
   - Se puede asignar a una variable para representar que esa variable está vacía o sin valor.
   - Por lo general, se usa cuando se espera un valor o un objeto, pero no se puede proporcionar uno válido.

   Ejemplo:

   ```javascript
   let miVariable = null;
   ```
2. `undefined`:

   - `undefined` se utiliza cuando una variable se ha declarado pero no se le ha asignado ningún valor o cuando se intenta acceder a una propiedad de un objeto que no existe.
   - Es un valor especial que se asigna automáticamente a las variables que no se inicializan con un valor.
   - A menudo, `undefined` se utiliza para indicar un estado indefinido o error en el código.
   - También puede ser el valor de retorno de una función si no se especifica un valor de retorno explícito.

   Ejemplo:

   ```javascript
   let miVariable; // Declaración de una variable sin asignarle un valor, por lo que es undefined
   let objeto = {}; // Un objeto vacío, pero objeto.propiedad no existe, lo que devuelve undefined
   function sinValorDeRetorno() {} // Esta función no devuelve nada, lo que equivale a return undefined;
   ```

En resumen, `null` se utiliza cuando deseas indicar explícitamente que una variable no tiene un valor válido, mientras que `undefined` se utiliza en situaciones en las que una variable no ha sido inicializada o cuando se intenta acceder a una propiedad inexistente en un objeto. Ambos son valores que indican la falta de algo, pero se usan en diferentes contextos y situaciones.

Puedes verificar si una variable es `null` o `undefined` utilizando varios métodos. Aquí tienes algunas formas de hacerlo:

1. Usando el operador de igualdad estricta (`===`):

   ```javascript
   if (miVariable === null) {
     // La variable es null
   }

   if (miVariable === undefined) {
     // La variable es undefined
   }
   ```

   La ventaja de usar el operador de igualdad estricta (`===`) es que verifica tanto el valor como el tipo de la variable, lo que significa que solo será verdadero si la variable es exactamente `null` o `undefined`, y no si es `false`, `0`, una cadena vacía (`''`), etc.
2. Usando la operación de igualdad débil (`==`):

   ```javascript
   if (miVariable == null) {
     // La variable es null o undefined
   }
   ```

   La operación de igualdad débil (`==`) es menos estricta y tratará `null` y `undefined` como iguales entre sí, por lo que esta condición será verdadera si la variable es `null` o `undefined`, pero también si es `false`, `0`, `''`, etc. Es importante tener cuidado al usar esta forma de comprobación debido a su flexibilidad.
3. Usando el operador `typeof`:

   ```javascript
   if (typeof miVariable === 'null') {
     // La variable es null
   }

   if (typeof miVariable === 'undefined') {
     // La variable es undefined
   }
   ```

   El operador `typeof` te permite verificar el tipo de una variable. Ten en cuenta que `typeof null` devuelve `'object'`, por lo que esta comprobación solo es útil para verificar `undefined`.
4. Usando el operador `== null`:

   ```javascript
   if (miVariable == null) {
     // La variable es null o undefined
   }
   ```

   Esta forma de comprobación es similar a la segunda opción pero es más concisa y se usa comúnmente en JavaScript para verificar si una variable es `null` o `undefined`.

Cualquiera de estas opciones puede ser útil dependiendo de tu caso de uso específico. La elección dependerá de si deseas una igualdad estricta o débil y de si también deseas considerar otros valores como iguales a `null` o `undefined`.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta de OP. OP pregunta cuál es la diferencia entre ambas.

Comment: Tienes razón, no agregue la definición de null y undefined, pero ya mismo la pongo

Answer (score 0):

En javascript, una variable con valor `null` se refiere a una variable que su tipo de dato ha sido indicado como `vacio` o `nulo`, un dato que representa un valor vacio, es decir una variable que `tiene valor`, pero su valor es `nulo` o `vacio` por lo que no representa ningun tipo de dato.

Mientras que `undefined` es el tipo de dato por defecto que se le asigna a cualquier variable si no se le ha especificado un dato por defecto, ademas, `undefined` representa a una variable `SIN` valor.